# Send email with attached file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail, google-docs

I am trying to send an email with an attached file by using google app script.
My workflow is:

1. Get data from Google Sheets
2. Create a Google Doc that contains the data
3. Send an email with the attached file, after conversion from Google Doc to MS Document.

1,2 works great for me, when I try to send the document, I get a file without content (no text in it). I'm trying to start with a pdf version, it will be very useful to understand how to implement the conversion to .docx format (or .doc).
Thank you!

My code looks like that:

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('File to attach');
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('some text insied the document');

  var subject = "mail subject";
  var body = "text within the mail"
  var fileId = doc.getId();
  
  var myMail = "myMail@domain.com";
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

  var blob = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(myMail, subject, body, {attachments:[blob]});
```

Comment: This seems similar to [this thread](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/send-an-email-with-attachment-using-google-apps-script).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a google doc to a pdf results in blank pdf, google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112528/converting-a-google-doc-to-a-pdf-results-in-blank-pdf-google-scripts)