# Converting a google doc to a pdf results in blank pdf, google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Here is my code to create a google doc paste some information in (eventually from a spreadsheet), convert it to a pdf and email it to myself.

Unfortunately, while the document in drive has the 'This document was created by Google Apps Script.' comment in it, The pdf in the email does not. It has the right title but the content of the page is lost. I have tried several examples on stack overflow and have not got one so far to work.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen(){
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
ui.createMenu('TEST MENU') //creates main menu tab 
   .addItem('pdf', 'pdf') 
   .addToUi(); 
}

function pdf() {
  // Create a new Google Doc named 'Hello, world!'
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello, world!');

  // Access the body of the document, then add a paragraph.
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This document was created by Google Apps Script.');

 var pdfContent = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
 var draftMail = GmailApp.createDraft('will@exampleEmail.co.uk',
                                   'Email title', 'Pls see attached', 
                                   {
                                     attachments: [pdfContent.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
                                     name: 'Converted doc content'
                                   });
// Now send the mail
draftMail.send();
}
```

Comment: You need to use saveAndClose before exporting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exported PDF is blank if merge and export functions are run from the same Apps Script function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213702/exported-pdf-is-blank-if-merge-and-export-functions-are-run-from-the-same-apps-s)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You're not saving and closing the doc before converting it to pdf**, maybe that's why your changed is not flushed out.

Try something like this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('TEST MENU') //creates main menu tab 
        .addItem('pdf', 'pdf')
        .addToUi();
}

function pdf() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello, world!');
    doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This document was created by Google Apps Script.');
    doc.saveAndClose()

    var pdfContent = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
    var draftMail = GmailApp.createDraft('will@exampleEmail.co.uk',
        'Email title', 'Pls see attached', {
            attachments: [pdfContent.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
            name: 'Converted doc content'
        });
    draftMail.send();
}
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose

Comment: spent 3 hours looking for this answer. The exact same issue I had.

Comment: i have this same problem but apps script says .saveAndClose() is not a function. Any update ?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling it on a Document object ? If yes, maybe ask another question with sample code.