# Google Apps Script - Variables not replaced before email is sent

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, google-docs

I have a Google Apps Script that generates a document in Google Docs by replacing variables between {{ }} with data from a Google Sheet. The script then converts the document to a PDF and sends it by email. However, when I receive the email, the variables have not been replaced.

When I check my Google Drive while the code is running, I can see that the document is generated and the variables are replaced, but it seems like it takes a while, first the document is saved with variable not replaced then the variable are replaced. Since the pdf are actually sent without variable being replaced my guess is that the email is sent before the variables being replaced.

I tried to add a 10 seconds sleep before sending the email but the result is the same.
Note that `console.log(body.getText());` log properly logging the text with all variables replaced.

How can I ensure that the variables are replaced before the email is sent? or more simply asked, how to make this script works if my guess is wrong...

```
function generateInvitations() {
  // Open the Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get the data range for the sheet
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  
  // Get the values in the range
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  // Get the template document
  var template = DriveApp.getFileById("1Fgve9aS6jGT3NbV6e_VcdkudDGvKv_cgUtg51DQus");
  
  // Loop through each row in the sheet
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    // Get the values for the current row
    var firstName = values[i][0];
    var lastName = values[i][1];
    var meetingTime = values[i][2];
    var zoomLink = values[i][3];
    var email = values[i][4];

    // Get the template document
    var docId = DriveApp.getFileById("1Fgve9aS6jGT3NbV6e_VcdkudDGvKv_cgUtg51DQus").makeCopy("Invitation from xxxxxx").getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId)
    body = doc.getBody();
    // Replace placeholders with data from the sheet
    body.replaceText("{{first_name}}", firstName);
    body.replaceText("{{last_name}}", lastName);
    body.replaceText("{{meeting_time}}", meetingTime);
    body.replaceText("{{meeting_url}}", zoomLink);
    body.replaceText("{{today}}", new Date().toLocaleDateString());
   

    console.log(body.getText());
    pdf = doc.getAs("application/pdf");

  

    // Email the PDF file to the recipient
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Zoom Meeting Invitation", "Please see attached invitation letter for your scheduled meeting", {
      attachments: [pdf],
      name: "Ecol Loco",
      subject: "Zoom Meeting Invitation"
    });
    
    // Delete the copy of the document
    DriveApp.getFileById(docId).setTrashed(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your script, please put `doc.saveAndClose()` just before the line of `console.log(body.getText());` and test it again. Or, please replace `pdf = doc.getAs("application/pdf");` with `doc.saveAndClose(); var pdf = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBlob();` and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose) I think that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52112528

Comment: It woks! added `saveAndClose()` before the `console.log()`, many thanks. Thank you for your lightening fast answer too.

Comment: Ho really? I spent time searching for an answer here but can't find anything. I'm really sorry that's a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Please don't worry. I think that your question is an important question for a lot of users. So, I think that even when the question is flagged as a duplicated question, the importance is existing.